# Calling a Web API secured by Azure B2C using .NET 5

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net5

I'm trying to call a Web API secured by Azure B2C. I'm using .NET 5. I'm also using Azure B2C to secure my WebApp.

In my WebApp `startup.cs` I have:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"))
   .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
   .AddDownstreamWebApi("API", Configuration.GetSection("AzureB2API"))
   .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I'm using `ITokenAcquisition` to get the access token. I tried `IDownstreamWebApi`, but that didn't work.

```
string accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(Scopes);
```

The problem I'm having is that, the version of the access token I'm receiving is version 1. However, the Web API is expecting version 2.

I tried to change the version to 1 in the manifest of the Azure B2C WebAPI (`accessTokenAcceptedVersion`) but it will not accept the change.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

The startup.cs of the Web API is:

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below can be a work around.

AddInMemoryTokenCaches adds an in memory token cache provider, which will cache the Access Tokens acquired for the downstream Web API.

> services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration,
> "AzureAdB2C")
> .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { Configuration["TodoList:TodoListScope"] })
> .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
> services.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

So,you may clear the cache after changing the accepted version so that app doesn’t take the previous version which is cached  and used till it got expired.
[reference1](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C)

As you mentioned the Web API is expecting version 2, I think you may have to change the accessTokenAcceptedVersion to 2 in the manifest of the Azure B2C WebAPP  that calls the web api in the portal.

```
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
```

> Note
>
> 1. If the value of Supported account types is Accounts in any
>    organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g.
>    Skype, Xbox, Outlook.com), the accepted token version must be v2.0.
> 2. Otherwise, the accepted token version can be v1.0
> 3. If the value is 2, the web API accepts v2.0 tokens.
> 4. If the value is null, the web API accepts v1.0 tokens.

Other points:
Also do check for the scope and permissions [Protected web API app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration#accepted-token-version)

> / The ASP.NET core templates are currently using Azure AD v1.0, and
> compute   // the authority (as {Instance}/{TenantID}). We want to use
> the Microsoft Identity Platform v2.0 endpoint
> **options.Authority =
> options.Authority + "/v2.0/";**

Also see [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C#about-the-code)

Comment: My WebApp is using a Sign In user flow. I believe this is where the problem lies. When I test the user flow with a reply URL https:/jwt.ms. and specify an access token return based on my WebAPI scopes. It returns a version 1 access token. How do I ensure that the user flow returns a version 2 access token.